# How to set time limit using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a little game with python. I already set everything but I would like to set a time limit. I found something on the internet but it is not working with this project but it works with another project.

```
c.create_text(450, 20, text = 'Time', fill = 'red')
c.create_text(650, 20, text = 'Score', fill = 'red')
time_text = c.create_text(450, 20, text = 'Time', fill = 'red')
score_text = c.create_text(650, 20, text = 'Score', fill = 'red')
def print_score(score) :
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text = str(score))
def print_time(time) :
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text = str(time))


ENNEMY_CHANCE = 10
TIME_LIMIT = 30
SCORE_BONUS = 1000
score = 0
bonus = 0
end = time() + TIME_LIMIT

#Main
while True :
    if randint(1, ENNEMY_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_ennemy()
    move_ennemies()
    hide_ennemies()
    score += ennemy_kill()
    if(int(score/SCORE_BONUS)) > bonus:
        bonus += 1
        end += TIME_LIMIT
    print_score(score)
    print_time(int(end - time()))
    window.update()
```

But I get this:

```
    end = time() + TIME_LIMIT
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

If you know an easier way to set a time limit that would be super.

Comment: `int` is indeed not callable, you probably redeclared `time` import with your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import time? I think you used the "time" name as an integer variable somewhere in your code and you have ambiguous code. Try this to get current time:

```
import time as time_module
now = time_module.time()
```

Comment: Yes. You are true. I set time as a variable above this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import time   
start = time.time()         #the variable that holds the starting time  
elapsed = 0                 #the variable that holds the number of seconds elapsed.  
while elapsed < 30:         #while less than 30 seconds have elapsed    

elapsed = time.time() - start #update the time elapsed
```